# Can we use "although" and "but" together i.e. in one sentence?

Tags: american-english, conjunctions, british-english, negation, redundancy

Is this a correct English sentence?

> ***Although,*** I'm not very clear about the reason, **but** that's where the problem lies.

Can *'although'* and *'but'* be used together in one sentence?

Comment: With the current lack of context, I assume this is quoted text from someone speaking "naturally" (i.e. not from a script or prepared statement). It will be easier for others to answer your question if you can provide the context in which this sentence occurred—a link to the source, if available, would be particularly helpful.

Comment: Obviously, you got your answer long ago.
I am curious about the source of this sort of error. Ahmad points out that equivalent constructions in Persian (among other languages are possible). What about your own native language, Zhengquan Bai?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Although* and *But*, both can be used separately to introduce a statement that make your main sentence surprising

> It's an old car, but it's very reliable
>
> Although it is an old car, it's very reliable.

But in your sentence, you used both of them together, as

> Although it is an old car, but it's very reliable.

This can be grammatical in some languages (like Persian) and it may provides more emphasis in those languages, but you actually don't need both of them in a sentence in English.

Comment: But is it correct?

Comment: In Chines they use both also.

Answer (score 4):

Since 'although' as a subordinating conjunction implies or introduces a contrast idea and 'but'as a coordinating conjunction contrasts an idea, ideally both may go against the understanding that they negate each idea. Therefore, they both may be ineffective when used together. In addition, as what was mentioned in the first comments,'although' which introduces a subordinate clause as in "Although, I am not very clear about the reason" will need an independent clause. 'But', on the other hand, should join the independent clause " that's where the problem lies" with another independent clause; thus, making the latter not the independent clause of the former.

Answer (score 2):

You should not.

One very common error with the usage of the conjunctions although and but is illustrated below:

Although/But

- WRONG -   Although these products are expensive but retailers have no problem selling them.
- CORRECT -

  Although these products are expensive, retailers have no problem selling them.

  These products are expensive but retailers have no problem selling them.

  Although these products are expensive, yet retailers have no problem selling them.

Source of above examples is
[cdtl.nus.edu.sg](https://web.archive.org/web/20190823031414/https://www.cdtl.nus.edu.sg/wrg/conjunction.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not very clear about the reason, but that's where the problem lies.

When you use although as a subordinate conjunction to introduce a subordinate clause, there must be a main clause to complete the sentence.
So if you use although as a subordinate conjunction in one clause and but as a coordinate conjunction in the other clause, the sentence will be incorrect grammatically.

Besides, the placement of the although in the sentence doesn't seem correct.  I would rephrase the sentence as follows:

I am not very clear about the reason, but that's where the problem lies.

Alternatively, you can use although instead of but because although is also used in the sense of but.

I am not very clear about the reason, although that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know,'Although' simply has same meaning of 'but'. It is quite odd to use together in one sentence. For example, althoughshe is very beautiful but selfish.
Instead of this, it is better to leave out one of them to have a clear meaning.
'she is very beautiful but selfish'.
Hope this helpful.!!!